# Bounds and infinite series involving log

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The motivation of the question is the Chebyshev Bound in the context of Analytic Number Theory but I do not think the context matters too much here, nevertheless, the statement was $\exists C> 0$ such that for all $x\geq 2$, $\pi(x)\leq C\frac{x}{log x}$.

Question: I was wondering how to prove that there exists a $C$, positive, such that $\forall x\geq 2$ this inequality holds: $$\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{log(\frac{x}{2})}+\frac{\frac{x}{4}}{log(\frac{x}{4})}+\frac{\frac{x}{8}}{log(\frac{x}{8})}+\cdots\leq C\frac{x}{log(x)}?$$

I did some digging on the internet and I found this quite useful [link](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Chebyshev.pdf) and I tried to follow Exercise 8. I think I managed to do it but here is my issue: it felt like that I was doing '$\forall x, \exists C>0$ such that the above inequality holds' rather than '$\exists C>0$ such that $\forall x$ the inequality holds'.

So if someone could please help me with proving this inequality, it would be much appreciated as the method I linked above did not convince enough.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: How could that hold for $x=2,4,\dots$?

Comment: @zhw. Ah yes, thank you! So I guess the real statement is for each $x$, there exists a constant such that the inequality holds and so the approach in the link was valid.

Comment: Not for each $x$! But for $x\notin \{2^k\}$ it would be enough to show the left side converges. The right side doesn't really matter.